# Correspondence between ideals of $R$ and $D^{-1}R$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, ideals

Let $R$ be an integral domain, and $D\subset R$ be a multiplicatively closed subset such that $1\in D$ and $0\not\in D$ . Prove/disprove that there is a one-to-one correspondence between the ideals of the ring of fractions $D^{-1}R$ and the ideals $I$ of $R$ such that $I\cap D=\emptyset$.

I've shown that every ideal in $D^{-1}R$ is the extension of some ideal in $R$ and that an ideal $I\subset R$  is a contraction of some ideal in $D^{-1}R$ if and only if ($\forall d\in D, x\in R:dx\in I\implies x\in I$).

I think that this fact is false but I can't find a counterexample.

Comment: What happens if $0 \in D$?

Comment: @Jim: sorry, I forgot some hypothesis.

Comment: Ok, take $D = \{1\}$, which ideal extends to the ideal $D^{-1}R$?

Comment: The ideal $R$, but I don't see the point.

Comment: But $R$ intersects $D$, it's not part of the correspondence.

Comment: Now I can see it. And if we only consider the proper ideals of $D^{-1}R$, can we find a counterexample too?

Comment: Yep, posted as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $A = k[x, y]$ and $D = \{1, x, x^2, \ldots\}$.  The ideals $(y)$ and $(xy)$ are distinct in $A$ and neither intersects $D$, but when we invert $x$ they become the same ideal.